# cannot handle alert message

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using *Java* and *Selenium* to write a test. My *Chrome Browser* version is 52.0 and my selenium driver is 2.53. I have a button on my target web page that after clicking on that an alert is shown. I always used :

```
 try{  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("blabla"))).click();
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
                    driverChrome.switchTo().alert().accept();
   }
    catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

to handle the alert, but since this morning, when test clicks on the button the alert pops up but then right after that it throws:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from unexpected alert open
 (Session info: chrome=52.0.2743.116)
 (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353145 (343b531d31eeb933ec778dbcf7081628a1396067),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 33 milliseconds
```

it doesn't even get to second and third lines !!
the error is thrown by the first line

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("blabla"))).click();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using chromedriver version 2.20.

Here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1224&colspec=ID%20Status%20Pri%20Owner%20Summary was told that in 2.22 version this issue is fixed.

So, if possible, you can verify if your problem is fixed, by upgrading your chromedriver version to 2.22.

Answer (score 1):

I had come across this same thing with Chrome when the button which was being clicked was inside an iframe. Just ran the test in firefox. Refer to these 2 issues logged in chromium bug tracker -

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1362

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1224

```
     try{ 
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("blabla"))).click();

       }
        catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    Thread.sleep(1000);
                        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
                        driverChrome.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Comment: but it was working yesterday !! what's happened ? we have to use Chrome :(

Comment: Try catching the exception at the button click line, it throws a WebDriverException, and then check if the alert handling code works. You could experiment with sleep too.

Comment: please have a look to the edited question. it throws the error on the first line, it doesn;'t get to thread.sleep

Comment: it gets to `driverChrome.switchTo().alert().accept();` and waits tehre for ever

Comment: What is your chromedriver version? It seems it is 2.20... Upgrade it to 2.22 and 2.23 stepwise and check again